# Obtaining values from Duty Roster Excel file via C# Windows Forms? is this possible? if yes how?

Tags: excel, windows, forms

I am to make a duty roster application that can display their schedules for the week, and allow employees to apply for leave, as well as to recommend staff to return on days where there are not enough staff. The duty roster is set in an Excel file, the dates are grouped in 4 weeks (28 days) per row, with the actually duty roster allocation below the dates themselves. Is it possible to use C# windows forms to obtain values from an excel sheet based on the date in the windows form application? The excel sheet data do not have dates assigned to them.

If you guys have code I would greatly appreciate it as well as comments in the code as I am a new to programming. thanks guys :)